# Adding a column to a SQL database in AZURE

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am new to the AZURE environment.

I have a SQL Database on AZURE and I need to add 2 columns to a table. While I am in the Portal I do not recognize anything that will allow me to alter the design of a table. I am using SSMS 2012 but when I look at the database on the azure server I do not have the design option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

From SSMS:

- Connect to the databse
- Execute your `ALTER TABLE` statements to create the columns.

From the portal:

- SQL Databases
- Select the one you're working with
- Click Manage
- Log in
- New Query
- Execute your `ALTER TABLE` statements to create the columns.

The designer in SSMS is buggy and most people I talk to advise against using it.

Comment: Thank you my browser was blocking pops so I didn't see the login.

Comment: I trust the SSMS editors more than the Silverlight thing Microsoft put together. I'm continually frustrated with the lack of SSMS features when connected to SQL Azure.